# Youtube Live Streaming API usage limitations

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

`Youtube Live Streaming API` has really thorough documentation, and I went through it as well as usage examples. Recently I started to get 403 error.

The full signature of the error is:

```
Error calling POST 

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet%2Cstatus%2CcontentDetails: 

(403) Request is not authorized
```

And I can't find out the reason behind it. On a day start it was all working fine with a google account credentials and `OAuth` keys. Then after a few requests succeeded it went down with the `403`. Same credentials and keys were used.

I strongly believe there are limitations in play, but which are this limitations or how to bypass them I can't help to find in docs or elsewhere.

the code goes like this (up to the breaking point):

```
$liveStreamingApi = new LiveStreamingApi();
$youtube = $liveStreamingApi->setLiveBroadcasts($returnUrl, null, LiveStreamingApi::CREATE);

$broadcastSnippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
$broadcastSnippet->setTitle($model->name);

$broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime(STARTTIME);
$broadcastSnippet->setIsDefaultBroadcast('1');

$status = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
$status->setPrivacyStatus($privacy);

$broadcastInsert = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
$broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
$broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
$broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

$broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status,contentDetails', $broadcastInsert, array());
```

where $liveStreamingApi->setLiveBroadcasts sets all the essential scopes in https (force-ssl, youtube, youtubepartner)
$youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert throws the aforementioned error

Comment: Can you share your code and your whole request?

Comment: We have been running into the same issue and our quotas are nowhere near close to capacity

Comment: Same here, with only 168 request showing after test creating about 10 livestreams.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quota limitation on youtube API that limit your request that you can make in day. The default quota value it's 1000000 per day splitted for the whole day. however every API request cost a different number of quota points.If you pass your quota limit you'd get an error message that is insufficientLivePermissions.
you can check your quota usage here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost
however you can consider that a insert request cost about 1600 of quota.

Comment: I aware of quotas and have noticed that the calculator has it for Data Api, which is said to be a source for Live Streaming API but some points are missing there. e.g. we know how much video upload costs, though how much of it for a stream?

Comment: Anybody knows, surely it should cost much more then a video insert. I got the same problem developping my app. Youtube should give more documentation, there are unlisted request like bind and transition, and surely insert a broadcast or a stream have a huge quota.

Comment: After test creating about 10 livestreams, my quota shows 168. Not sure if my quota showing true

Comment: Was live streaming one day and my app stopped working cause I somehow hit 10k chat requests and was blocked. Didnt have time to check only a few days later I checked the analytics nothing showed me 10k anymore.. also.. how dumb is it that I can have the stream open on a TV, laptop and phone for 6 hours and not hit a limit.. but my bot hit it after 3 hours.. allegedly - cause I cant find the problem any way. Google is weird